# Celery: Schedule a new task to run after an existing task finishes

Tags: python, celery

Lets say I have the following celery tasks:

```
# tasks.py
@app.task
def taskA():
    time.sleep(10)
    return "result"

@app.task
def taskB(result):
    print("got result")
```

In my program I regularly start new `taskA` tasks like this:

```
res = taskA.apply_async()
keep_for_later(res.id)
```

Then, sometimes during execution of my program, for some conditions, I need to run a `taskB` task after a `taskA` task has finished.

```
taskA_id = get_task_id()
if condition_is_met():
    res = app.AsyncResult(taskA_id)
    # How can I tell celery to run a `taskB` task at earliest when this `taskA` task has finished,
    # and with the output from taskA as input to taskB ?
```

I am running a separate celery worker as follows:

```
celery -A tasks worker
```

I need both tasks to run asynchronously on the worker separate from the main program.
Using celery v5.3.6 on Ubuntu.

Please note that this code i highly simplified and may not run as-is, but hopefully the question becomes clear enough.

EDIT:

I found the following to work:

```
# tasks.py
@app.task
def taskA():
    time.sleep(10)
    return "result"

@app.task
def taskB(task_id):
    res = celery_app.AsyncResult(task_id)
    with allow_join_result():
        taskA_result = res.get()
    # do stuff with taskA_result
```

Then, later:

```
taskA_id = get_task_id()
if condition_is_met():
    taskB.apply_async((taskA_id,))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why canvas (chains) is not a solution for you? https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chains

Comment: To my understanding, when using the `link` option with `apply_async`, the chain is established at the time I call taskA.apply_async and taskB will always run. Am i right? In my case I only know if I want to run taskB at a later time.

Comment: No, if `taskA` ends up in a failure for example, `taskB` wouldn't run. Alternatively, you can add `task_condition` in between, a quick one that fails if a condition isn't met or retries several times. I can elaborate on an answer if that's an option for you